# Glaswegian Scottish English: What does Limmy say at 01:01?

Tags: scottish-english

Binging on Limmy's sketches has given me quite an ear for Glaswegian, but I still can't make out what he says at 01:01 in the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uH0hikcwjIA

Kinda sounds to my ears like "n'chongn" or something like that. Any help? :D

Comment: Sounds like he’s saying “I’m joking”, but his continued perplexity doesn’t really fit that very well… Maybe “I’m choking”? (Though why would he be choking?) Very hard to tell without the benefit of a whole sentence to give more context.

Comment: He uses the same phrase in this sketch too:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzGROTt7QsA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I live in Scotland and I get the message

> "Video unavailable. This video contains content from LDS, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds."

That means all the people who would be most likely to know can't see the video. I managed to find another site by Googling "Limmy's Show - What's heavier?" I couldn't find @spiffles example from their comment.

I'm certain he's saying "A'm joking" which is Scots for "I'm joking". When he realizes he's making a fool of himself, he tries to pretend to himself that he is just taking the pish (as we say here) - that is, making a joke at other people's expense. But he does not convince himself and admits to himself that he doesn't really understand and he wasn't making a joke.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! BTW, would you mind also elaborating on the second example? The video you can't see can be found on youtube by "limmy - stashed childhood". He says the same phrase towards the end.

Comment: Sorry @spiffles but all roads lead to LDS. The BBC has the copyright in this country and their player says "Not available at this time". They are obviously planning to rebroadcast it or sell the local rights having already sold the foreign rights to LDS. Wish I could help!

Comment: Not that I'm insisting on further help from you, but you could try using this:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unlimited-free-vpn-hola/gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio?hl=en

Works like a charm for bypassing country-based restrictions, at least in my experience.

Comment: @spiffles I've watched it. It's difficult for me to be certain, especially as I'm not Glaswegian, or even Scots. We think that we speak as precisely as we write but we  don't. We often say things that sound OK until you replay them and then you realize they simply aren't clear. Once when I was doing a Gaelic course the teacher played us a recording of the weather forecast. He thought he understood it, but when we played it back and listened very careful he had to admit there were bits he simply couldn't be sure about.

Comment: @spiffles My best guess is that he is saying "Ah---\[you're\] joking". "You're joking" is one of those phrases that is used frequently, and often with very little meaning. Often it is used to express annoyance with an outcome, but it can also be used, with Glaswegian irony, to express the idea that an outcome is better than could have been expected. Here I think he is saying "That is so kind of you that I do not believe you. Are you sure you are not about to say you were just joking?". This is very Scottish humour.